# Scikit-learn binarize categorical data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I've been trying to load a CSV file into scikit via pandas and setting the target column to be a list of  20 categorical variables. I've tried using label_binarize but that didn't seem to do any good so after some reading I've switched to LabelEncoder but it doesn't appear to change much.

```
from io import StringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import permutation_test_score
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize, MultiLabelBinarizer, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

#loading the data
data=pd.read_csv("data.csv")
y = data.iloc[:,19]
X = data.iloc[:,1:18+20:22]

#Binarize the output
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(["0-1","1-1.5","1.5-2","2-2.5","2.5-3","3-3.5","3.5-4","4-4.5","4.5-5","5-5.5","5.5-6","6-6.5","6.5-7","7-7.5","7.5-8","8-8.5","8.5-9","9-9.5","9.5-10","10+"
])
LabelEncoder()
le.transform(y)
y = label_binarize(y, le)
n_classes = y.shape[1]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.5,
                                                random_state=0)

model3 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=7)
```

yet when I run this I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "file, line 30, in <module>
le.transform(y)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 149, in transform
classes = np.unique(y)
File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py", line 198, in unique
ar.sort()
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

Is this kind of target data even possible for scikit?

Comment: Can you post the complete code. The code you have posted does not match with the stack trace of error.

Comment: @VivekKumar I've added some of the extra stuff, no real point in adding the rest because it fails before it get to running the model.

Comment: Which version of scikit are you using? Also show some samples of y. Are you sure that those are from the values you used in le.fit(). If I take y values from those , then its working for me as expected.

Comment: Also, LabelEncoder will only convert the string to integer to numerical. Will not binarize them. For binarizing you have to use the label_binarize or LabelBinarizer. By the way, most scikit estimators (including KNeighborsClassifier) will handle strings in target (y) without any issue. So why is the need of encoding them in your scenario?

Comment: @VivekKumar worked out what the problem was had to surround the actual data with quotation marks to get it to recognise them as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so to solve this issue I found you needed to surround the categorical data itself with quotation marks like this: "0-1"

Otherwise Python would read it as the long of 0-1 and get confused. The data loads correctly.